# compare multislect pick list with another picklist

Tags: picklist, validation-rule, configuration, multi-select

I have a multislect picklsit on User object and a picklist on case object, I am trying to write a validation rule so that if picklist value selected on case is not matching with one of the multislect value on user, it should throw error
I am using the below formula but it's not working, I also tried containing a function with no luck, any guidance would be appreciated

```
NOT(INCLUDES($User.ServiceCategory__c, TEXT(ServiceCategory__c)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiselect Picklists have limited functionality in formulas, i.e. only a very limited amount of functions are supported.

For a purpose like this, indeed `INCLUDES` is the only function you can use. Unfortunately, `INCLUDES` only supports a text literal as second parameter, not a text variable.

If you want to stay away from using APEX code, I suggest the following solution:

1. create a new text field on User called e.g. ServiceCategoryCopy. Don't put it on the page layout. It can be read-only for all profiles except admin.
2. create a record-triggered flow on User (before insert/update) that copies the multi-select picklist value to the ServiceCategoryCopy field
3. create your validation rule using the `CONTAINS` function instead of `INCLUDES`

Note that this only works if the multi-select picklist values do not have overlapping text, as `CONTAINS` will not match exact picklist values but will match the text of the picklist with a concatenated string of all multiselect picklist values.

The other alternative is to write an APEX trigger. There you have the opportunity to split the selected multi-select picklist options into separate strings and compare them one-by-one with the selected picklist value on Case.